# Object is possibly 'undefined' ts, even if i checked it before

Tags: typescript

##### Hi, I am new in this, I am using typescript and I have this error:

###### Object is possibly 'undefined'*.ts(2532)*

```js
if (listStre[i]?.bokFolder?.length && listStre[i].bokFolder.length > 0)
```

my variables

```js
const listStre: Streamer[]
(property) Streamer.bokFolder: chrome.bookmarks.BookmarkTreeNode[] | undefined
// bokFolder is a bookmark folder of chrome
```

i think bokFolder can not be undefined because i checked it before, and neither .length

[image: error on vs code]

Comment: You don't need to check if it's greater than 0. `listStre[i]?.bokFolder?.length` will do fine

Comment: oh i see, you are rigth, but the problem with that is eslint give me a warning:
Unexpected nullable number value in conditional. Please handle the nullish/zero/NaN cases explicitly.eslint@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to check if the length is greater than 0, but to please TypeScript and ESLint, you would need to move the item into a variable:

```
const bokFolder = listStre[i]?.bokFolder;

if (bokFolder?.length && bokFolder.length > 0) { ... }
```

See the related issues below:

- [#23512](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23512)
- [#14957](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14957)

---

and here's why you don't need to check if the lengths are greater than 0:

```js
console.log(Boolean(undefined && undefined > 0)); // false
console.log(Boolean(0 && 0 > 0)); // false
console.log(Boolean(1 && 1 > 0)); // true, no point in checking if it's greater than 0
console.log(Boolean(-1 && -1 > 0)); // never going to happen since lengths can't be negative
```

Comment: it works, thanks, it makes sense why i don't need to check for `length > 0`, but if i just put: `if (bokFolder?.length)` eslint complains: Please handle the nullish/zero/NaN cases explicitly. Thanks for the answer